# Angular & D3.js: Why is element[0] undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am working on an angular application and just starting to work with D3.js.

I am following along on a tutorial to create custom directives.

```
<my-chart></my-chart>
```

I am doing this:

```
...

.directive('myChart', function () {
    function link() {
        var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append('svg'); 

        ...

    return {
        'link': link,
        'restrict': 'E'
    }
})

...
```

But I am always getting back `ReferenceError: element is not defined`

If I give my directive an id, then everything works:

```
...
var svg = d3.select(document.getElementById('myChart')).append('svg');
...
```

I am not sure why as since I am able to talk to the `element` when it has an id, I don't think it's a timing problem. But, I don't know what else it could be. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: And where is `element` coming from, it's not declared anywhere in the posted code ?

Comment: This would be the root of my  problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you haven't specified `element` in link function, and you were looking for element which is undefined. You should have `element` in your `link` function to get access to angular compiled DOM.

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
```

Comment: Thank you Pankaj! It's painfully obvious I am learning both - that was exactly what I was missing.